# Type parameterization and strange cast exception

Tags: scala, type-parameter

I have the following code which splits an array into an array of arrays before any element that satisfies the predicate `p`. It type checks:

```
def splitBefore[T](a: Array[T], p: (T) => Boolean)
      (implicit tct: ClassTag[T]): Array[Array[T]] =
  a.foldLeft(Array[Array[T]](Array.empty[T])) {
(acc: Array[Array[T]], s: T) => if (p(s))
  acc :+ Array(s)
else
  acc.init :+ (acc.last :+ s)
}
```

It works fine when I call it with non-empty `a`:

```
scala> splitBefore(Array("a", "BC", "d"), (s: String) => s.size > 1)
res1: Array[Array[String]] = Array(Array(a), Array(BC, d))
```

But when I call it with an empty array, I get a `ClassCastException`:

```
scala> splitBefore(Array.empty[String], (s: String) => s.size > 1)
java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [[Ljava.lang.String;
  ... 33 elided
```

When I hand-inline the call so there is no type parameterization, it works fine:

```
scala> Array().foldLeft(Array(Array.empty[String])) {
     |   (acc: Array[Array[String]], s: String) => if (s.size > 1)
     |     acc :+ Array(s)
     |   else
     |     acc.init :+ (acc.last :+ s)
     | }
res1: Array[Array[String]] = Array(Array())
```

Any idea what's going on here?  I'm using Scala 2.11.7.

Comment: I'd say it's a bug. Generated bytecode is just plain wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like instantiating a nested array causes a bug - it crashes even on such a small example:

```
def instantiate[A](ununsed_arg: Array[T])(implicit tag: ClassTag[A]) =
  Array[Array[A]](Array.empty[A])
```

As a quick workaround, you might use an ArrayBuilder to create an array:

```
def instantiate[T](a: Array[T])(implicit ctc: ClassTag[T]) = {
  val builder = ArrayBuilder.make[Array[T]]
  builder += Array.empty[T]
  builder.result
}
```

Also please note that your snippet directly appends elements to an array, which is a bad idea because it has to create a new array with one more slot and copy an element. Looks like you should either use an `ArrayBuilder` or `ArrayBuffer` to do the processing or build your new data structure out of Lists and convert them to `Arrays` at the end.